# Converting an RGB image to grayscale for a whole dataset in Python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bokJ2.jpg)I am new to python programming. i have to convert my dataset rgb images to grayscale then have to apply cycleGAN on that dataset.i am using zelda levels dataset.I have no idea how and haven't found many useful things from looking through the internet. If someone could point me in the right direction, so I can figure out how to either change it to a one channel image or grayscale that would be great.

Comment: Use OpenCV to convert RGB to Grayscale

Comment: dear mate, please focus on more basic python skills and follow some tutorials, then you can solve these on your own easily. you mis understood how packages can be imported. So, learn some basic python, it can help you out.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

remove this red marked line and it should be fine.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help but this does nt work.